# Is there a name for $n \times n$ matrices $M$ satisfying $M^2 = n M $?

Tags: matrices, reference-request

I stumbled upon $n \times n$ matrices $M$ which have the property that:

$M^2 = n M $

Is there a name for these matrices? Thanks for your help.

**Edit**:
The matrix definition is:

$$M = ((-1)^{d(i,j)})_{1\le i,j \le n}$$

where $d(i,j)$ is the length of the shortest path from $i$ to $j$ in a given graph of $n$ vertices. The graphs which I am interested in are bipartite, so there are no odd cycles, and with this property, one can prove that:

$$M^2 = nM$$

Example matrix:

$$\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrr}
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1 \\
-1 & 1 & 1 & -1 & 1 & -1 \\
1 & -1 & -1 & 1 & -1 & 1
\end{array}\right)$$

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I will update the question with more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are simply projection matrices multiplied by $n$, and so they have all the same (or very closely analogous) nice properties as projection matrices.

To see this, let $P = M/n$ so that
$$
P^2
= M^2/n^2
= M/n
= P
$$
so that $P$ is a projection matrix.

This allows us to find all such $M$ - namely, they are the matrices whose eigenvalues are $0$ and $n$.

Comment: Thanks. I must admit I did not see this immediately, so the stupid question.

Comment: Did you mean the eigenvalues should be 0 and 1?  The identity matrix for example.

Answer (score 3):

Already the case $n=2$ shows that there will me much more general solutions than $M=nI$ or $M$ a matrix with entries $\pm 1$. Indeed, all matrices
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix} a & b\cr \frac{a(2-a)}{b} & 2-a\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $b\neq 0$ satisfy $M^2=nM$ with $n=2$.

I am not aware of a special name for such a class of matrices. Of course one may relate it to a projection matrix $P$ with $P^2=P$ by setting $P=\frac{1}{n}M$. Then
$$
P^2=\frac{1}{n^2}M^2=\frac{1}{n}M=P.
$$

Comment: Thanks for your insight in this quesiton. Do you know of a name for the $M$ matrices defined as above?

Comment: As I said, I am not aware of a special name. It is a bit related to [projections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)). But your matrices deserve a name, more than just $M^2=nM$. This is like studying prime numbers, and asking for a name of $p\bmod 2$. There will not be a special name, I suppose.

Comment: Why is it related to projections?

Comment: It says $P^2=P$. This is similar to $P^2=nP$, but of course different.

Comment: Yes I read it, those matrices are called idempotent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent_matrix but I do not see how to transform $M$ into one idempotent matrix.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I thought maybe the $M^2=n M$ had a special name so I gave it a try asking here.

Comment: Let $M^2=nM$ and set $P:=\frac{1}{n}M$. Then $P^2=P$.

Comment: Thanks! I saw already in the answer of Damian. I must admit, I had not seen this . :-(